# how do i link frontend and backend in flask

Tags: python, flask, url, database-connection

I'm building a web app using flask. I'm still beginner at coding and I'm still trying to understand and grasp the concepts. so i

-

---

---

worked on building a text summarizer and chatgpt chatbot model then worked on the front end . Now im trying to integrate the frontend with the backend but im unable to link the urls properly . these are the html templates and app.py file

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <!-- basic -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <!-- mobile metas -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
      <!-- site metas -->
      <title>MyClassroom</title>
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <!-- bootstrap css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- style css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <!-- Responsive-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
      <!-- fevicon -->
      <link rel="icon" href="images/fevicon.png" type="image/gif" />
      <!-- Scrollbar Custom CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">
      <!-- Tweaks for older IEs-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" media="screen">
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
   </head>
   <!-- body -->
   <body class="main-layout">
      <!-- loader  -->
      <div class="loader_bg">
         <div class="loader"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="#" /></div>
      </div>
      <!-- end loader -->
      <div class="wrapper">
      <!-- end loader -->
      <div class="sidebar">
         <!-- Sidebar  -->
         <nav id="sidebar">
            <div id="dismiss">
               <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
               <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
               <li><a href="#about">About </a> </li>
               <li><a href="#work">Work</a> </li>
               <li><a href="#contact">Contact </a> </li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
         <!-- header -->
         <header>
            <!-- header inner -->
            <div class="header">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col logo_section">
                        <div class="full">
                           <div class="center-desk">
                              <div class="logo">
                                 <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="#" /></a>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                        <ul class="btn">
                          <li>
                            <a href="teacher-login.html" class="teacher-btn">Login as Teacher</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="down_btn">
                            <a href="#">Download</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">
                              <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse">
                              <img src="images/menu_icon.png" alt="#" />
                            </button>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      
                      
         <!-- end header inner -->
         <!-- end header -->
         <!-- banner -->
         
         <!-- about --><div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide banner_main" data-ride="carousel">
           <ol class="carousel-indicators">
             <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
             <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
             <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
             <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
           </ol>
           <div class="carousel-inner">
             <div class="carousel-item active">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                 <div class="carousel-caption">
                   <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                       <div class="text-bg">
                         <h1>AI<br> Notes <br>Summariser</h1>
                         <p>Effortlessly condense study materials. Save time, Enhance comprehension, Learn efficiently with intelligent summarization technology</p>
                         <a href="summary.html" class="read_more">VIEW</a>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                       <div class="images_box">
                         <figure><img src="images/img2.png"></figure>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="carousel-item">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                 <div class="carousel-caption">
                   <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                       <div class="text-bg">
                         <h1>Get<br> Latest <br>Notes</h1>
                         <p>All class notes at your fingertips. All class notes at your fingertips. All class notes at your fingertips. All class notes at your fingertips</p>
                         <a href="page2.html" class="read_more">VIEW</a>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                       <div class="images_box">
                         <figure><img src="images/img2.png"></figure>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="carousel-item">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                 <div class="carousel-caption">
                   <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                       <div class="text-bg">
                         <h1>Classroom<br> Attendance <br>Feature</h1>
                         <p>Teachers can take real time attendance which can be accessed by students. All class notes at your fingertips All class notes at your fingertips</p>
                         <a href="page3.html" class="read_more">VIEW</a>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                       <div class="images_box">
                         <figure><img src="images/img2.png"></figure>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="carousel-item">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                 <div class="carousel-caption">
                   <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                       <div class="text-bg">
                         <h1>AI<br>Chatbot</h1>
                         <p>Powerful tool for improving student learning outcomes and building a more dynamic and engaging learning environment</p>
                         <a href="{{ url_for('chatbot') }}" class="read_more" target="_blank">VIEW</a>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                       <div class="images_box">
                         <figure><img src="images/img4.png"></figure>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
             <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           </a>
           <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
             <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           </a>
         </div>
         <!-- end banner -->
         <div id="about"  class="about">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="row d_flex">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                     <div class="about_img">
                        <figure><img src="images/about_img.jpg" alt="#"/></figure>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                     <div class="titlepage">
                        <h2>About <span class="blu">MyClassroom</span></h2>
                        <p>MyClassroom is a comprehensive virtual classroom web application designed to revolutionize the way students and teachers interact in the digital learning space. With an intuitive interface and a range of powerful features,
                           MyClassroom fosters seamless collaboration, efficient learning, and easy access to educational resources. From real-time attendance tracking to AI-powered chatbot assistance and note management, MyClassroom empowers students and teachers to thrive in a dynamic and engaging online learning environment. Join MyClassroom today and experience the future of virtual education.</p>
                        <a class="read_more">Read More</a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- end about -->
         <!-- choose  section -->
         <div class="choose ">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <div class="titlepage">
                        <h2>Why <span class="blu">MyClassroom</span></h2>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="choose_bg">
               <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 padding_right0">
                              <ul class="easy">
                                 <li class="active"><a href="#">COMPLETE CLASS NOTES</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">AI NOTES SUMMARISER</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">REAL-TIME ATTENDANCE</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="chatbot.html">AI POWERED CHATBOT</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 padding_left0">
                              <div class="choose_box">
                                 <i><img src="images/admin.png" alt="#"/></i>
                                 <h3> Ad Minim</h3>
                                 <p>MyClassroom is a comprehensive virtual classroom web application designed to revolutionize the way students and teachers interact in the digital learning space. With an intuitive interface and a range of powerful features, MyClassroom fosters seamless collaboration, efficient learning, and easy access to educational resources. From real-time attendance tracking to AI-powered chatbot assistance and note management, MyClassroom empowers students and teachers to thrive in a dynamic and engaging online learning environment. Join MyClassroom today and experience the future of virtual education.MyClassroom fosters seamless collaboration, efficient learning, and easy access to educational attendance and resources.</p>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- end choose  section -->
         <!-- work -->
         <div id="work"  class="work">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="row d_flex">
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                     <div class="titlepage">
                        <h2>How To <span class="blu">Works it</span></h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit </p>
                        <a class="read_more">Read More</a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                     <div class="work_img">
                        <figure><img src="images/work_img.jpg" alt="#"/></figure>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- end work -->
         <!-- request -->
         <div id="contact" class="request">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <div class="titlepage">
                        <h2>Request <span class="white">A call Back</span></h2>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <form id="request" class="main_form">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-12 ">
                              <input class="contactus" placeholder="Full Name" type="type" name="Full Name"> 
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              <input class="contactus" placeholder="Email" type="type" name="Email"> 
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              <input class="contactus" placeholder="Phone Number" type="type" name="Phone Number">                          
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Message" type="type" Message="Name">Message </textarea>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              <button class="send_btn">Send</button>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <div id="map"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- end request -->
         <!--  footer -->
         <footer>
            <div class="footer">
               <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
                              <div class="address">
                                 <h3>Address </h3>
                              </div>
                              <ul class="location_icon">
                                 <li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, </li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                              <div class="address">
                                 <h3>Links</h3>
                                 <ul class="Menu_footer">
                                    <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#about">About </a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#work">Work</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact </a> </li>
                                 </ul>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
                              <div class="address">
                                 <h3>Follow Us</h3>
                              </div>
                              <ul class="social_icon">
                                 <li><a href="#">Facebook <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#"> Twitter<i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#"> Linkedin<i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#"> Youtube<i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#"> Instagram<i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                              <div class="address">
                                 <h3>Newsletter </h3>
                              </div>
                              <form class="bottom_form">
                                 <input class="enter" placeholder="Enter Your Email" type="text" name="Enter Your Email">
                                 <button class="sub_btn">subscribe</button>
                              </form>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="copyright">
                  <div class="container">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                           <p>Copyright 2019 All Right Reserved By <a href="https://html.design/"> Free  html Templates</a></p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </footer>
         <!-- end footer -->
      </div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <!-- Javascript files-->
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
      <!-- sidebar -->
      <script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
                 theme: "minimal"
             });
         
             $('#dismiss, .overlay').on('click', function() {
                 $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
                 $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
             });
         
             $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
                 $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
                 $('.overlay').addClass('active');
                 $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
                 $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
             });
         });
      </script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                 openEffect: "none",
                 closeEffect: "none"
             });
         
             $(".zoom").hover(function() {
         
                 $(this).addClass('transition');
             }, function() {
         
                 $(this).removeClass('transition');
             });
         });
      </script>
      <script>
         // This example adds a marker to indicate the position of Bondi Beach in Sydney,
         // Australia.
         function initMap() {
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             zoom: 11,
             center: {
               lat: 40.645037,
               lng: -73.880224
             },
           });
         
           var image = 'images/maps-and-flags.png';
           var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: {
               lat: 40.645037,
               lng: -73.880224
             },
             map: map,
             icon: image
           });
         }
      </script>
      <!-- google map js -->
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA8eaHt9Dh5H57Zh0xVTqxVdBFCvFMqFjQ&callback=initMap"></script>
      <!-- end google map js -->
               </div>
            </div>
         </header>
   </body>
</html>
```

chatbot.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
 <form method="post" action ="{{ url_for('chatbot')}}">
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message" required>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>


  </form>

<!--<p><strong>You:</strong>{{ user_input }}</p>-->
<!--<p><strong>Chatbot:</strong>{{ bot_response }}</p>-->
<!--  <form method="post" action ="{{ url_for('chatbot')}}">-->
<!--    <label for="message">Message:</label>-->
<!--    <input type="text" id="message" name="message" required>-->
<!--    <button type="submit">Send</button>-->


<!--  </form>-->

<!--</body>-->
</html>
```

summary.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #100da1;">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Summarizer</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <form action="/summarize" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" style="padding-top: 2em;">
          <strong>Enter Your Text Below To Be Summarized:</strong>
        </label>
        <br />
        <textarea
          class="form-control"
          id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
          rows="10"
          name="data"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <br />

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Summarize</button>
    </form>
</head>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Your Summary</title>
    <style>
      p {
        padding-top: 2em;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 3em;
        color: black;
        word-spacing: 0.25em;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
      }
    </style>

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav
      class="navbar navbar-light"
      style="background-color: hsl(236, 96%, 22%);"
    >
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Text SUMMARY</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <p>{{ result }}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.py

```
#importing flask
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
#Importing the summarizer
from summarizer import Summarizer
from summarizer.sbert import SBertSummarizer
import openai


openai.api_key = 'xyz'
# Using an instance of SBERT to create the model
model = SBertSummarizer('paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder="templates")

@app.route("/")
def msg():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/summarize", methods=['POST','GET'])
def getSummary():
    body=request.form['data']
    result = model(body, num_sentences=5)
    return render_template('summary.html',result=result)

@app.route("/chatbot",methods=["POST"])
def chatbot():
    user_input = request.form["message"]
    prompt=f"User :{user_input}\nChatbot:"
    chat_history=[]
    response= openai.Completion.create(
        engine="text-davinci-002",
        prompt=prompt,
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=60,
        top_p=1,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        stop=["\nUser:","\nChatbot:"]
    )
    bot_response =response.choices[0].text.strip()
    chat_history.append(f"User: {user_input}\nChatbot: {bot_response}")

    return render_template(
        "response.html",
        user_input=user_input,
        bot_response=bot_response,
    )





if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.debug = True

app.run()
```

im unable to link the chatbot.html and summary.html file properly. I also need to build in an attendance monitoring system and notes uploading system using a database i could use some advice on that as well .
Thank you